# Best Way to Create Records in a SQL Server Database to Meet Performance Requirements

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I'm currently developing a database system to store the result data from a machine. The data is arriving from the machine via an ethernet connection to a C# application which parses the data and creates records for the data in the database. Our calculations suggest we need to create at least 12000 records a second to keep up with the machine. These records are spread accross ten or so tables.

My initial tests are giving us at most 1800 records per second on one table. My C# code is along the lines of:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("insert tablename (column names) values (values)", connection);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
```

which I will admit is a naive attempt.

My questions are:

1. Is this record creation rate feasible and
2. What's the best method to acheive the require rate?

Database: SQL Server 2008

Language: C# 2.0

Answer (score 2):

If the data is coming in too fast to be loaded in the database "in real time", then:

- Upgrade, get better hardware and software. Of course, the new setup may still not be fast enough (and will you be able to test it before shelling out the $$ ?)
- Defer. Have C# (or whatever, if C# isn't fast enough) stream the data into a formatted file (comma delimited, XML, whatever) somewhere, and periodically close it off, start a new file, and have SQL load the data found in the "last" file.
- SQL 2008 R2 has a "Stream Insight" feature that *might* be applicable here, though I'd definitely call it an advanced subject.

Mind you now, 12000 rows at 1 byte per second is a bit under 1 GB a day... if you have 100 bytes per row, that's a bit under 100 GB a day, and 30 TB a month.  Are you sure about those numbers?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm very sure about the numbers. We've estimated about 2GB per working day, the system will only be running during office hours usually.